# Why can I not build and run this in Code blocks?

Tags: c

[image]**Here is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b = 9;
    printf("input a integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n",a,b,a+b);
    return(0);
}
```

*Build message:*

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
ld.exe||cannot open output file G:\document\C++ and C\Add and Input.exe Permission denied|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I think my code is right. But I can't get it right to run smoothly.

Comment: Because your project/IDE is badly configured: no compiler.

Comment: Your code looks right (apart from treating `return` as a function) so the reason is in the parts that you don't show here. Guessing from the error, you haven't created an actual project that could be compiled.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: `return(0)` is valid in C.

Comment: In codeblocks, you must first create a project, then select that project in the tree on the left, then you can make a new file, select "console application", follow the menus, select "C" and the name of the program, you will then see it appear with a "hello world" template code, replace it with your current code, then run it

Comment: The brackets are superfluous, @machine_1, which is what I'm taking offence at. Of course, that doesn't make the code invalid in any way but it's a bad habit IMHO.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: For the record, those are "_parenthesis_"

Comment: `ld.exe||cannot open output file G:\document\C++ and C\Add and Input.exe Permission denied|`  Your program did compile, but you set up your IDE to write the compiled program to a bad location.

Comment: There _is_ a problem with your code, but it's not a problem that makes it fail to compile.  [`scanf` should not be used to read input interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf).  (I would go farther and say that none of the `scanf` functions should ever be used at all.)

Comment: @zwol There are so many alternatives. what do you recommend for replacing ```scanf```?

Comment: Don't use `+` in a directory name in Microsoft OS

Comment: @M.M, You mean this G:\document\C ```++``` and C\Add?

Comment: If you can create it in Explorer, it is probably a valid path, @M.M. At least that's what I would assume. It may well be that some programs are buggy, like that they can't handle paths with spaces. I'm very confident the OS is capable of handling valid paths, speaking from XP being the last version I used.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt can all 3rd party tools handle it though?

Comment: I meant exactly that, @M.M: "It may well be that some programs are buggy" BTW: That also implies that if a change to the directory name causes the thing to suddenly compile without problems, then it's a bug in one of the used programs and deserves a bug ticket.

Comment: @kile The discussion I linked to gives several good suggestions for avoiding `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to configure your project with CodeBlocks (in my case the project name is "containers").

**1 - right click on your project icon :**

[image]

**2 - select "build options for debug or/and release:"**

[image]

**3- select "compiler settings" and then check the box corresponding to your option :**

[image]

Comment: I can't find there is a project. It's just a c file. I write this with "Ctrl-Shift-New". Anyway, thank you for your answer.